# AWS Appsync Graphql Get the Newly created item Id

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to save a new item to a graphql model, and then get the newly created item id and then use it to save to another table.

Here is the code I'm using for creating the new item

```
import { DataStore } from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
import { Tenants } from "./models";

DataStore.save(
      new Tenants({
        agency_name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      })
    );

//Now, Here I will do my stuff with the newly created tenant Id.
```

Thanks a lot